# Code documentation comments for ASP.NET razor pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

Is it possible to add code documentation comments to razor pages (resp.: components)?

I found it possible to use standard documentation comments for page parameters (which are declared in @code blocks), but I am still looking for a way to add comments for the component (class) itself.

For parameters, this works:

```
@code
{
   /// <summary> The Id of the selected account. </summary>
   [Parameter]
   public int SelectedAccount { get; set; }
}
```

So, for a class, it should be something like this:

```
@***
    <summary> This component renders a table. </summary>
***@
```

or

```
@classcomment{
    <summary> This component renders a table. </summary>
}
```

Does anyone know a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible just from `.razor` files. However, you can add a "code-behind" file where you could place the documentation (this is not ideal, of course, because the documentation is separate from the Razor code).

For example, let this be your `Component.razor`:

```
<p>Some component</p>

@code
{
   /// <summary> The Id of the selected account. </summary>
   [Parameter]
   public int SelectedAccount { get; set; }
}
```

You can create `Component.razor.cs` with the component's documentation comment (the filename is not important, but it's a nice convention to follow this scheme):

```cs
/// <summary> This component renders a table. </summary>
partial class Component { }
```

Note that the namespaces must match (in this example I haven't used any, but you could specify namespace via `@namespace` directive in the `.razor` file or folder structure, and `namespace` block in the `.cs` file as usual).

Comment: I found this out, too. Obviously it's not what I wanted, but technically it answers the question. Might help someone else still.

Comment: Yes, while not ideal, creating a single C# file for all the component descriptions (empty partial classes) isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "it cannot be done", for now.

I've opened a [feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/7862) on the razor repo. **If you want this feature, please upvote it!**

Until this is possible, the accepted answer is a very nice workaround (but requires an extra file, which is a nuisance).