# Adding Xml Documentation for Razor components (no code behind)

Tags: razor, blazor, xml-comments

i have seen a similar question here but only with code behind:

[Adding XML documentation for Razor components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70604351/adding-xml-documentation-for-razor-components)

am I forced to use code behind for a razor component to add Xml Documentation to it?

Comment: IMO code-behind is a good thing to do as you split your view and "controller".

Comment: I use intheritance a lot in my components, this led me to build render fragments on the fly a lot in the oninitialized method mixing more the ui with the code making code behind worse than actually keeping all in one file, I wouldnt be able to initialize render fragments in the oninitalized method with the razor syntax from the code behind or at least not without making a huge mess

Comment: @IvanAmbla I think your question is totally valid, and I'm looking for the same information. There are definitely instances where a code behind is either difficult like you said, or just plain overkill.

Comment: @IvanAmbla You can define your render fragments as private methods/properties in a `@code` section in the razor file, and then call them from your `OnInitialized` in the code-behind.  (I don't have a better answer to your question than "add a code-behind" though; I came here looking for one.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code documentation comments for ASP.NET razor pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263893/code-documentation-comments-for-asp-net-razor-pages)

Comment: Nope, this just suggest to add code behind, ty anyway!